# PHP Fatal error Could not include the language file Opencart

Tags: php, themes, opencart, lang

I have installed opencart and I have also installed Arabic language and pavillion theme and I followed the documentation, but I get this problem:

```
PHP Fatal error: 'Could not include the language file /home3/smartgpt/public_html/project/catalog/language/english/default.php'
in /home3/smartgpt/public_html/project/tb_themes/pavilion/library/ResourceLoader.php:143
Stack trace:
#0 tb_themes/pavilion/library/ThemeManager.php(722): TB_ResourceLoader->loadOcTranslation('default')
#1 tb_themes/pavilion/catalog/ThemeCatalogExtension.php(302): TB_ThemeManager->loadOcTranslation()
#2 tb_themes/pavilion/catalog/ThemeCatalogExtension.php(94): Theme_Catalog_Extension->setLanguageDirection()
#3 tb_themes/pavilion/library/vendor/sfEventDispatcher.php(81): Theme_Catalog_Extension->afterRouting(Object(sfEvent))
#4 tb_themes/pavilion/library/CatalogDispatcher.php(130): sfEventDispatcher->notify(Object(sfEvent))
#5 tb_themes/pavilion/library/CatalogDispatcher.php(66): TB_CatalogDispatcher->doRouting(Object(sfEventDispatcher), Object(Request), Object(TB_ViewDataBag))
#6 tb_themes/pavilion/catalog/boot.php(48): TB_CatalogDispatcher->dispatch(Array)
#7 catalog/controller/common/tb_themes.php(32): TB_Boot::bootTheme(Object(Registry), Object(Front), 'pavilion', 0)
#8 [internal function]: ControllerCommonTbThemes->index(Array)
#9 system/modification/system/engine/action.php(65): call_user_func(Array, Array)
#10 system/modification/system/engine/front.php(42): Action->execute(Object(Registry))
#11 system/modification/system/engine/front.php(37): Front->execute(Object(Action))
#12 system/modification/system/engine/front.php(17): Front->dispatch(Object(Action), Object(Action))
#13 index.php(243): Front->addPreAction(Object(Action))
#14 {main}
```

Comment: As your OC is 2.X version .. is your theme also compatible with V2.X ?

Comment: The problem might be because to your theme. Try to change default theme from admin panel and check that does it work or not. And is the problem still exist then try changing default language. May be your new language pack is creating a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to : /catalog/language/english/ ... Download english.php > rename to default.php > upload back to /catalog/language/english/

Because it is saying, that it could not include language file, because there is no such file in /catalog/language/english/ directory.
Helped for me.